# Activating VR disconnects second monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-reality

I have an HP Reverb G2 and 2 monitors. I use the second monitor to extend my desktop. When runing Mixed Reality Portal, the headset activates but it also deactivates the second monitor. To reactivate it, I have to go in the display settings, select the second monitor and choose Extend desktop to this display. The problem is that it doesn't save this choice for when VR is active. I have to do it each time.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the computer? What graphics card?

Comment: AMD 5600X + RTX 3080